# Преобразование из hex в ieee 754 half precision

Tags: c#, ассемблер

Есть данные в хексе вида D0 58 3E. Необходимо перевести это ieee 754 half precision. Есть такой [конвертер](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), но он одинарной точности (32 бита, а мне именно 16 бит надо).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Byte[] data = new Byte[7];
  Int32 bytes = sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
  string all = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```